Add Array to Array of Objects with new key / value to existing Array of Objects in JavaScript
I want to take an existing array and add it to the existing array of Objects. I want to add a new key with values from reasons. Please help.
Array:
const reasons = ['a', 'b', 'c']; 

Array of objects that look like:
[
    {
        id: 1,
        Data: 'yes',
        active: true
    },

    {
        id: 2,
        Data: 'yes',
        active: false
    },

    {
        id: 3,
        Data: 'data',
        active: false
    }
]

Result want:
[
    {
        id: 1,
        Data: 'yes',
        active: true,
        reason: a
    },

    {
        id: 2,
        Data: 'yes',
        active: false,
        reason: b
    },

    {
        id: 3,
        Data: 'data',
        active: false,
        reason: c
    }
]


Yes, sorry! I got it mixed up. I have already tried to create a key  but obviously cannot have same existing keys in an object.. with the array. I just have no idea how to approach this.

You can achieve this by mapping over your existing array of objects and adding the values from the reasons array to each object. Here's a simple way to do this in JavaScript:
Example:
const reasons = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

const data = [
  { id: 1, Data: 'yes', active: true },
  { id: 2, Data: 'yes', active: false },
  { id: 3, Data: 'data', active: false }
];

const result = data.map((item, index) => {
  return {
    ...item,
    reason: reasons[index]
  };
});

console.log(result);

Output:
[
  { id: 1, Data: 'yes', active: true, reason: 'a' },
  { id: 2, Data: 'yes', active: false, reason: 'b' },
  { id: 3, Data: 'data', active: false, reason: 'c' }
]


A simple map function can accomplish this for you.
const reasons = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

const obj = [
  {id: 1, Data: 'yes', active: true},
  {id: 2, Data: 'yes', active: false},
  {id: 3, Data: 'data', active: false}
];

const merged = obj.map((reason, index) => {
  // .reason is your new key, and it gets it from reasons[index]
  reason.reason = reasons[index];
  return reason;
});

The new value of merged:
[
  { id: 1, Data: 'yes', active: true, reason: 'a' },
  { id: 2, Data: 'yes', active: false, reason: 'b' },
  { id: 3, Data: 'data', active: false, reason: 'c' }
]

I hope that's what you were going for and that this helped.

Simplest way is to loop through each object and add reason to it


const reasons = ['a', 'b', 'c']
const objects = 
[
    {
        id: 1,
        Data: 'yes',
        active: true
    },

    {
        id: 2,
        Data: 'yes',
        active: false
    },

    {
        id: 3,
        Data: 'data',
        active: false
    }
]
const result = objects.map((obj, i)=> ({...obj, reason : reasons[i]}))
console.log(result)



